# Protractor debugging using ng e2e

Tags: node.js, angular, protractor, e2e-testing, angular-e2e

I could debug e2e tests by running below command separately -

```
node --inspect-brk .\node_modules\protractor\bin\protractor .\e2e\protractor.conf.js
```

However, I'd to run **'ng e2e'** separately along with above command for debugging which opens up two browser, one for e2e and another for debugging e2e. I wanted to run e2e tests at once in debug mode with a config/command in package.json for debug mode.

I came across below command to get it to run with ng  -

```
node --inspect-brk ./node_modules/\@angular/cli/bin/ng e2e ./protractor.conf.js
```

I've following in package.json -

```
"e2e": "ng e2e -c=integration --suite e2e --webdriverUpdate=false"
```

I  was trying to use debug command following way -

```
"e2e-debug": "node --inspect-brk .\\node_modules\\@angular\\cli\\bin\\ng e2e -c=integration --suite e2e --webdriverUpdate=false" .\\e2e\\protractor.conf.js
```

on hitting **chrome://inspect/#devices** and inspecting, it stopped in first line of ng. I got **Unknown option: '.\e2e\protractor.conf.js'** error later and execution stopped.

I removed **.\e2e\protractor.conf.js** from above command and tried like below -

```
"e2e-debug": "node --inspect-brk .\\node_modules\\@angular\\cli\\bin\\ng e2e -c=integration --suite e2e --webdriverUpdate=false"
```

For this, while inspecting,it stopped at first line of ng and later it never stopped at any spec file where debugger was present. It completed running tests without stopping anywhere.

Any idea how I can use ng e2e command with options while debugging?

Comment: highly recommend to consider an option to debug with vs code

Answer (score -1):

I have written an article on Debugging protractor tests. If you have not referred already please take a look.
https://medium.com/@ganeshsirsi/how-to-debug-protractor-tests-in-visual-studio-code-e945fc971a74